# Bad Gateway nginx for docker container

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I was trying to find out what is the problem for last 4 Hours, but had no luck.
I have two containers. PHP and nginx. First in `docker/php/dockerFile`:

```
FROM php:7.2.2-fpm

...

# Install Composer
...

# install node and npm
...

WORKDIR /var/www/

COPY post_run_web.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/post_run_web.sh
```

and the second one in `docker/nginx/dockerFile`:

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD ./vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /var/www
```

and in `docker/nginx/vhost.conf`

```
...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
...
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
  frontend:
      driver: bridge
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: dockerFile
    container_name: "TEST_web"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - backend

  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      dockerfile: dockerFile
    container_name: "TEST_php"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - backend
    tty: true
    entrypoint: ["/usr/local/bin/post_run_web.sh", "dev"]
  ...
```

I start my containers with `docker-compose up`. The problem is that my TEST_php container stoped automatically because of my `post_run_web.sh` in `entrypoint` option. So I added `tail -f /dev/null` in `docker/php/post_run_web.sh` to keep container running:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www
composer install
npm install
npm run $1

tail -f /dev/null
```

Now I see that all containers a running but get `Bad Gateway nginx` error when trying to access via browser. If I remove entrypoint from `yml` file, and try to execute `post_run_web.sh` manually after container started, everyting works fine.
How can I fix it and keep my entrypoint option?

Comment: did you try to expose port 9000 on app service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been struggling with this the past few days. Some common problems I found are:

- Not exposing the 9000 (or whatever other port php-fpm is listening on). This looks like your case.
- php-fmp configuration: It can use a unix socket instead of listening in that
  port. Look for in the php-fpm config. The listen directive should be `listen = 0.0.0.0:9000`. You may need to `ADD/COPY` the configuration.
- The php-fpm service may not be running
- The containers may not be linked (not your case)

I suspect that the problem may be that php-fpm is not started because you defined your own entrypoint, overriding the default php-fpm7.2 image's entrypoint which starts the service. Try starting the service in `post_run_web.sh`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, works fine after I've added `php-fpm -F -R` at the end of `post_run_web.sh`